# Best way to represent a song, consisting of an arbitrary number of chords?

Tags: sqlite, model, schema

How can I best represent the following data in sqlite3?

I'm creating a database of songs, each of which consists of an unpredictable number of chords. Each chord has a root (string, 1 or 2 characters) and a tonality (string, <20 characters).

It would make intuitive sense to me to have two classes: *Chord* containing two strings, and *Song* containing an arbitrary-length list of *Chord*s. However, as far as I can tell, that's not how sqlite operates. Is there a better/canonical way of handling this type of data?

EDIT:

There is a specific constraint to this problem that the order of the chords is important, and I don't think the typical SQL one-many relationship satisfies that.

Comment: SQLite indeed does not use classes; it uses tables. Do you know how to model a 1:N relationship in SQL?

Comment: I think so: I could use a table of chords, each with an ID#, and a table of songs, each with a string of chord IDs. Is that what you meant?